# passing custom php.ini to phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

How to pass a custom php.ini to phpunit?

The source uses

```
get_cfg_var
```

instead of

```
ini_get
```

so unfortunately it doesn't use values set by ini_set, -d option etc.

Only way to pass the value now is to use an additional php.ini. How do I pass that into phpunit?

**Gory details:**

I tried passing in with -d

```
phpunit --filter testgetdesc -d SIEF_VALIDATOR_DOC_ROOT="htdocs" 
--configuration tests/phpunit.xml tests/configHelperTest.php

public function testgetdesc() {
    echo get_cfg_var("SIEF_VALIDATOR_DOC_ROOT")."---test---";
}
```

It simply echoes  "---test---"

The reason is this uses ini_set as well:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php

```
            case 'd': {
                $ini = explode('=', $option[1]);

                if (isset($ini[0])) {
                    if (isset($ini[1])) {
                        ini_set($ini[0], $ini[1]);
                    } else {
                        ini_set($ini[0], TRUE);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Also in the phpunit.xml, I have

```
<php>
  <ini name="SIEF_VALIDATOR_DOC_ROOT" value="bar"/>
</php>
```

which doesn't work [and I don't expect it to].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-d` should work because PHPs [`get_cfg_var()` function](https://php.net/get_cfg_var) reads those:

```
$ php -d display.errors2=1 -r "echo get_cfg_var('display.errors2');"
1
```

To pass a custom ini setting (or alternatively the ini file with `-c <file>` to phpunit), invoke it configured:

```
$ php -c <file> -d setting=value $(which phpunit) <your-params>...
```

---

References/See as well:

- `php --help`, [Command line options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php), [Executing PHP files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php), [`get_cfg_var()` function](https://php.net/get_cfg_var)
- PHPUnit Docs: [Command-Line Options](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/textui.html#command-line-options), [The XML Configuration File](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html)
- Shell: `$( ... )` [Command Substitution (Bash GNU Reference)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), `which`: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/9340)

Comment: I don't think phpunit passes it on to php - please see my edit above.

Comment: I confirmed, it won't work from code - https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php

Comment: @Fakrudeen: I added an alternative, no problem to invoke phpunit that way.

Comment: awesome - that works great! Another [a bit more drastic] option is to use export PHPRC=. and add a php.ini in current dir.

Answer (score 0):

The [Github issue](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/940) recommends using the `-c` flag.

```
php -c custom-php.ini `which phpunit` ...
```