# With PHPUnit Class 'mysqli' is not found

Tags: php, mysqli, phpunit

I just started with [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/). Some simple tests I wrote are working. So in general PHPUnit is up and running. There's something wrong with the MySQLi class though.

In my code it works fine. Here's the line:

```
$this->mysqli = new \mysqli($this->host, $user->getUser(), $user->getPwd(), $this->db);
```

When this line is parsed running phpunit I get the following error message (pointing to that line):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/...
```

Two possibilities (as I see it):

1) I'm missing some feature / extension / configuration step / something else related to a correct setup of PHPUnit working with the MySQLi extension.

**EDIT**

If I do test for the extension `extension_loaded('mysqli')` it returns `true` in my normal code. If I do the following within the Test it skips the test (i.e. it returns `false`):

```
if (!extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    $this->markTestSkipped(
        'The MySQLi extension is not available.'
    );
}
```

**/EDIT**

2) There might be a problem with my code. I'm trying to mock a User object in order to make a test connection. So here it is:

```
<?php
class ConnectionTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $connection;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $user = $this->getMockBuilder('mysqli\User')
                     ->setMethods(array('getUser', 'getPwd'))
                     ->getMock();
        $user->expects($this->once())
             ->method('getUser')
             ->will($this->returnValue('username'));
        $user->expects($this->once())
             ->method('getPwd')
             ->will($this->returnValue('p@ssw0rd'));

        $this->connection = new \mysqli\Connection($user);
    }

    public function testInternalTypeGetMysqli()
    {
        $actual   = $this->connection->getMysqli();
        $expected = 'resource';

        $this->assertInternalType($expected, $actual);
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        unset($this->connection);
    }
}
```

The tested Connection class looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace mysqli;

class Connection
{
    protected $mysqli;
    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $db   = 'database';

    public function __construct(\mysqli\User $user)
    {
        $this->mysqli = new \mysqli($this->host, 
                                    $user->getUser(),
                                    $user->getPwd(),
                                    $this->db);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

    public function getMysqli()
    {
        return $this->mysqli;
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

This whole thing is / was an installation problem. I'm using a [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) installation which provides my PHP. Installing *PHPUnit* independently makes it use a different setup! So in my browser (XAMPP powered) all was fine, but in my command line the MySQLi extension has been missing all together! Debian provides a package called *php5-mysqlnd*. Having this installed all works fine! (except other errors appearing :-)

Comment: Are the [`mysqli` class requirements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.requirements.php) met? Exercise: Please demonstrate they are with a short test-code and it's output.

Comment: Other than it's working in my code? As I said: the code line produces a valid mysqli object if run by itself (ie. without phpunit). PHP is configured with mysqlnd (5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 310735 $)

Comment: If you run in shell, what gives: `$ php -r "new mysqli();"`? Which configuration is PHPUnit using? Please provide a proof that when you invoke PHP for PHPUnit that it's configured. PHP tells you the class does not exists, ergo: you have not configured the extension.

Comment: I'm on it! See my edit in the question. So far it seems that running from command line, the extension is missing! PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found in Command line code on line 1

Comment: So now on commandline do: `$ php -i | grep ini` and locate the ini file for commandline. Configure the ini file to load the extension and you're ready for testing. Alternatively, put the ini with all you require to your tests and tell phpunit to load that ini.

Comment: this one?! /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: that looks good. But see as well: [passing custom php.ini to phpunit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7723959/367456).

Comment: Thank You for the good pointers! Turns out I had to install a package called php5-mysqlnd (on debian!) As I'm using a xamp installation phpunit seems not to be accessing the same php installation!

Comment: Why do you use xamp when you're on debian? Debian comes with everything one could wish ;) I'll add the answer.

Comment: Historical reasons ... I'll set it up without in the very near future, as I now have the problem, that my mysql is running on a different location in the webbrowser as well!! So far I never had problems with that! It changed with phpunit ... +1 for the debian thumbs up!

Comment: Had this problem, but just a local build of PHP 5.5 using custom configure script from PHP 5.4. Apache SAPI worked fine but CLI would die of no mysqli_*, ini files were the same.  Stripping off the =mysqlnd parms from each of the mysql configure options in my configure 'build' script along with a make distclean and remake/install fixed the CLI access for me, YMMV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHPUnit normally runs within the CLI - command line interface.

The PHP you've got there is different than with the webserver. Different binary and often a different configuration as well.

```
$ php -r "new mysqli();"
```

Should give you the same error. Verify where the binary and configuration is located:

```
$ which php
```

And

```
$ php -i | grep ini
```

Ensure you've got [the extension for the `mysqli` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.requirements.php) installed and enabled. Once configured you should be able to run your unit-tests flawlessly.

Comment: This was a tricky one for me, it turned out to be a quirk in the binary build I was using.  Your tips helped me suss it out, thanks!