# PHPUnit undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, phpunit

When I try to connect to my MySQL database from PHP code all seems to be fine, all queries are executed successfully. However, when the code is tested with unit tests in PHPUnit, I get the following fatal PHP error:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect().

As indicated, this code works fine outside of unit tests, but PHPUnit generates errors.

Comment: Are you using two different PHP interpreters (maybe php-cli for one and php-cgi for the other)?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation processk](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Just quickly rewrote the mysql_ code, but now PHPUnit indicates the following: Class 'mysqli' not found. This is on the line where the equivalent of
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database"); is executed. Did I miss something? Do I need to include some file to use mysqli?

Comment: Are you perhaps using a namespace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [with phpunit class 'mysqli' is not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191869/with-phpunit-class-mysqli-is-not-found) - Please check if this answers your question, basically your PHP CLI configuration has no MySQL your question suggests.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you're using a namespace, and therefore `mysql_query` or `MySQLi` is undefined there.

Try the following:

```
$mysqli = new \MySQLi(...);
```

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid that's not the solution either. Same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're testing with a version of PHP 7 or higher.

In the [php documentation mysql_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), they describe the following

> Warning
> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
> mysqli_query()
> PDO::query()

So, two possible solutions:

1. Downgrade PHP to a lower version (< 7);
2. Replace your mysql functions with MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: If the function is actually undefined, then it's likely to be PHP 7.0 rather than 5.5. You can use the mysql funcs in 5.5 or 5.6 as long as you're willing to put up with deprecation warnings. But that said, the long term option has to be switching away from the deprecated functions and using PDO instead.

Comment: that's right Simba, I'll edit it.
This issue could be related to installation of php5-mysql module, if only the package php5-common is installed.