# PHPUnit, Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found

Tags: php, mysqli, phpunit

I have a similar to issue to that described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191869/with-phpunit-class-mysqli-is-not-found):

Everything works as I would expect; my code accesses the database and prints output irrespective of whether I run in from my command line interface or from the web browser. Same result. If I run it in Eclipse with PHPUnit, I get an error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found
    - Occurrence of 'connection'
```

Which points at the following line:

This code prints out 'Yes'.

```
$connection = new \mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);

if (extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo "Yes";
}
else {
    echo "No";
}
```

One more thing to point out is that I'm using my own namespace in the class where the above code is located. My unit tests are in the global namespace.

I've followed the steps in the URL above but, alas, to no avail. :(

Running this on the command prompt gives no errors:

```
php -r "new mysqli();"
```

Please could someone help me understand the issue here?

Comment: Why the backslash before mysqli?

Comment: Because without the backslash, it thinks mysqli is a function inside my namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you have configured your `php.ini` file with the correct path, either DLL or shared object (.so) file. Try running, if you're using Unix/Linux, on your command line,

```
$> php -i | grep mysqli
```

and see if it says something being installed, or create a PHP script

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Run that script and check if it's loaded correctly or not. If you are confident that it was really installed, try checking your php.ini file if it was loaded correctly by checking your "extension" section of php.ini.

Check also when running your PHPUnit, if it's in command line, because it might you have a different path for php.ini vs your php.ini when running in web mode.

Comment: 1) I think that mysqli has been installed correctly. It is present in phpinfo; i can access the database from the web interface; i can access the database from the command line prompt.

2) I'm not sure that I have two different php.ini files. whereis php .ini only returns one php.ini file.

Comment: if the extension is installed, then it's almost certainly using a different PHP.ini when you run it in eclipse that doesn't load the extension. The output of `phpinfo()` will tell you what extensions are loaded and what php.ini file is being used.